# bookmarklet that saves web page as-is and provides a link to it?

Tags: save-as, bookmarklet

I recall there was a site that provided a java bookmarlet that would save the web page as-is (not just a .jpg screenshot), and instantly provide you a link where you could view it. It apparently extracted the data straight from your browser so even if particular site could not be accessed unless you have an account on that particular site, it would still save its web page. It also didn't require me to install any programs, apps or anything.

It is not getpocket.com or evernote.com

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're describing a bookmarklet which uses the *Save Page Now* feature of the Wayback Machine at https://archive.org/web/ .

Putting the following URL in a bookmark will make a bookmarlet which submits the current page to the Archive's crawler:

`javascript:location.href='http://web.archive.org/save/'+location.href`

When it's done, it will give you a URL to retrieve the page later, such as this one:

https://web.archive.org/web/20151027184740/https://superuser.com/questions/992583/bookmarklet-that-saves-web-page-as-is-and-provides-a-link-to-it

Comment: It's not archive.org either, unfortunately. The service I'm describing could make EXACT copy of the page that you have opened in your browser through bookmark. So, for example, if you're logged in, it would also show your nickname in a nickname section and such. Not as if the page was re-opened by a bot that accessed the page and then saved it.